# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'todo_list.forms' in Django app

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial online for a to-do app using Django, but I keep getting this error.

> File “C:\DjangoStuff\my_app\todo_app\urls.py”, line 3, in
>   from todo_list import views
>   File “C:\DjangoStuff\my_app\todo_list\views.py”, line 3, in
>   from .forms import ListForm
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘todo_list.forms’

I have tried deleting and adding back the **forms.py** file, but no success. The todo_list folder does contain all the files being referenced as far as I can tell.

I have a todo_list folder where all the below mentioned files are stored

This is the code I have imported in the **urls.py** file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
```

in the **views.py** file, I have the following imported:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

I have also created the **models.py** file and **forms.py** files as part of the todo_list folder.

I'ms sure it's something simple but have been through the tutorial many times and cannot find anything wrong...

[File list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tpBu.png)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server after adding it back?

Comment: Please show your folder structure with mentioned files.

Comment: @nishitchittora Yes I have. I will try to restart my PC and see if it works. I haven't had such a problem before when I tried to build the same app.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks. I have uploaded an image under the link 'File List'. You'll see that it contains all the files under the todo_list folder.

Comment: Please tend to post info in text, not in pictures. Your forms.py is in wrong place. Move it one level up - to the folder where views.py lies.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Got it sorted thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your **forms.py** file should be in the folder `todo_list\`, not under `todo_list\templates\`
as it is now.

`from .forms import ListForm` in the **views.py** file expect to find the **forms.py** file in the same directory (**.**)

Other solution could be to let the file where it is now, but state instead in the **views.py** file `from todo_list.templates.forms import ListForm`

Comment: Thanks it is working. Gonna use another editor as I struggle to make out under which folder the files are situated. I'm still a noob ;)